# How can I add a widget to a listview dynamically when FAB is pressed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a simple form in which I want the driver to type in the orders' number he is taking out and send this data to my db, however, I cant know in advance how many orders he is taking so I want to start the form with just one text field and the driver can increment the text fields as much as he has orders by clicking on the FAB.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './order_widget.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  int count = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff403E3D),
        title: Image.asset(
          "assets/logo.png",
          width: screenWidth * 0.2,
          height: screenHeight * 0.5,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            count++;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffb6721c),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: screenHeight * 0.02,
                left: screenWidth * 0.42,
                bottom: screenHeight * 0.02),
            child: Text(
              'Orders',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ListBody(
                    children: [
                      OrderForm(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.02),
            child: Align(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: screenWidth * 0.2,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Color(0xffb6721c),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('Send'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have different options, but maybe using a for loop here is enough :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './order_widget.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  int count = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff403E3D),
        title: Image.asset(
          "assets/logo.png",
          width: screenWidth * 0.2,
          height: screenHeight * 0.5,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            count++;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffb6721c),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: screenHeight * 0.02,
                left: screenWidth * 0.42,
                bottom: screenHeight * 0.02),
            child: Text(
              'Orders',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ListBody(
                    children: [
                      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                        OrderForm(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.02),
            child: Align(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: screenWidth * 0.2,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Color(0xffb6721c),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('Send'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ListView.builder` as follow:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('${items[index]}'),
    );
  },
)
```

set `itemCount: count` and after increasing its value, you can use `List.generate()` as follow:

```
List<Widget>.generate(count, (int index) => YOUR WIDGET);
```